# With two subgroups of a group $G$, does one being a subset of the other imply being a subgroup of it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,\ast,e)$ be a group, and $(H,\ast,e)$ and $(K,\ast,e)$ be subgroups of $G$. If $K\subseteq H$, is $K \leq H$ ?

With the subgroup test, it seems trivial, but I just want to make sure I'm not making some stupid mistake, as I'm using this for another proof that's causing me to question everything.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Yeah.  The definition of subgroup is that it's a group (check) and a subset (check).  It's kind of .... meaningless. To talk of K being a group either all elements also elements of H but not a subgroup.  How exactly can a group *not* be a subgroup except by not being a subset.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is true. It follows immediately from *one step subgroup test*, that is

For K subset of H,

K is a subgroup of H if and only if:

1. K is not empty;
2. For every two elements $a,b\in K$ also $a^{-1}b\in K$

Can you check that these two conditions hold?

Comment: +1, but your *one step subgroup test* has two steps.... :)

Comment: ...or more directly, If and only if K is a group.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a fixed operation $*$ which is the same for all groups in the context, the statement *$K$ is a subgroup of $H$* just means that (i) *$K$ is a subset of $H$* AND (ii) *$K$ is a group.*

This applies in this case since $G, H, K$ are all using the same operation. Since $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, it's a group, and since it's a subset of $H$, by the above fact, it's a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Minor clarification: (ii) $H$ is a group *with respect to the operation in $G$.*

Comment: @KentaS Thanks, clarified.